# Which API or framework to use for building dashboards using Pentaho?

Tags: mdx, dashboard, pentaho, mondrian, cdf

I want to build an dashboard for which back end will be Pentaho community edition. I am using Mondrian and MDX queries.

I have tried to use Pentaho CDF for building dashboard but it seriously lacks documentation and without proper documentation its not possible to build dashboards. I am facing problem with lot of small things.

For example, I wrote one MDX query which returns sum of `sales` and `expenses` for each of the `department`. This MDX query works fine in `Analysis view` .

In `Analysis view` I am able to see bar chart different bars for `sales` and `expenses`. Then I used same MDX query in datasource of type `MDX over MondrianJNDI` CDE dahboard type and attached this datasource to `CCC Bar Chart` but `CCC Bar Chart` is displaying values for only `sales`.

So I would like to know how can I display same bar chart as I get in `Analysis view`?

Also, I would like to know how to create parametrized MDX query in Pentaho CDF? How to use `Dashboard Chart Java API`?

I am finding it difficult to use Pentaho CDF, so I want to  try other API or framework for building dashboards. What are other options available in this kind of scenario?

Please enlighten,

Thanks in Advance !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(disclaimer: I'm the lead developer for the CTools in general, and CDF in particular)

You'll find that CDF is indeed the most popular choice within the Pentaho community, and that in turn means that it's what the community itself will have the easiest time helping you with. Since your issue is documentation, I'm not sure how much you've explored what's already there. If you have Pentaho installed, from the Pentaho User Console head to the BI Developer Examples solution folder, and under CDF you'll find the CDF Documentation.

Alternatively, I suggest you give CDE a try (CDE is an editor that builds dashboards on top of CDF and CDA). You'll find a great tutorial for it [here](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?82766-CDE-tutorial-available).

Comment: Thanks a lot pdpi. I saw that example, its short but nice tutorial. I am using CDE only to build dashboards but I am facing problem in finding information about things like for example 'how to change title of an chart dynamically'? I am not able to find this information anywhere. Another example, in that tutorial one javascript function is present which is something like function(s,c,v){ Dashboards.fireChange('days',s); } . Where can I get information about this Dashboards class and what are its available methods, what are other classes available? this type of information I need.

Comment: That sort of docs are available in the BI Developer Examples solution folder, as I mentioned. Regarding parametrized queries in CDA, since you're using CDF, all you need is to insert ${myParam} in your query, and list myParam as a parameter in the parameters property for the datasource. You probably also want to set Crosstab Mode to true in your chart, to tell it it's dealing with an mdx-style resultset.

Comment: Thanks pdpi. Finally I managed to create parametrized MDX queries and stepped forward. Also, I found out the meaning of parameters to that function(s,c,v). Now I am stuck at displaying values in table, but I think I will get something on pentaho forum..

Answer (score 0):

(disclaimer:I'm working for icCube).

If you're keen going for a no free solution you can try [icCube OLAP server](http://www.iccube.com/) and their [GVI library](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/viz/doc/vizOverview.html). It's on the starting blocks but interesting if you want to build your own solution. You can see some examples [here](https://www.iccube.com/reporting/).

If you need support, paying for a little support it's a money and time saving solution (this for any solution you take). Community is nice, but there is a limit on the time people can spend helping other for free.

Comment: thanks.. I have seen icCube demo. Its much better than CDE but I cannot take licensed